# MYSQL: LEFT JOIN on TWO TABLES USED with Group_Concatenate

Tags: mysql, left-join, group-concat

I am running a query on a table where I also want to grab related information from two related tables, both of which are many to one relative to the primary table.

I am then sending this info through JSON to an app and for this reason am group_concatenating the multiple values from the other tables.  It works fine with one additional table.  However, when I add a second table, I am getting all of the byproducts of the two extra tables which I don't want.

Can anyone suggest how to get only unique values for the joined fields?

```
//current sql

$sql = SELECT c.*,group_concat(p.name) as `names`,
group_concat(l.location) as `locations`
FROM companies `c` 
LEFT JOIN people `p`
ON p.companyid = c.id
LEFT JOIN locations `l` 
ON l.companyid = c.id
GROUP by c.id;
```

The output basically multiplexes names repeating values for each name by location which I don't care about (and doing the same for locations).

Instead of

```
"names":"John,Joe,Jim,Tom,Bob","locations":"Tokyo,London,Manila,Paris,Milan",
```

the output is `"names";"John,John,John,John,John,Joe,Joe,Joe,Joe,Joe,...etc.`

Thanks for any suggestions on right way to do this.
Edit: Sample Data

```
  Companies
    id|company|
    1|IBM
    2|Google
    3|Apple
    4|Amazon

    People
    id|name|companyid
    1|John|1
    2|John|2
    3|Jim|3
    4|Bob|4
    5|Tom|4

    Locations
    id|name|companyid
    1|London|1
    2|Cupertino|3
    3|Seattle|3

Desired output: 
company:IBM, people:John, location:London
company:Google, people: John location: null
company:Apple, people:Jim location: Cupertino
copany:Amazon, people:Bob,Tom location:Seattle
```

Comment: You can use DISTINCT with GROUP_CONCAT to eliminate duplicates, but not quite sure that is what you want. Normally when I have needed something like this it is because I need a list of paired values, in which case I have used CONCAT() on the 2 fields, and then GROUP_CONCAT on the resulting values.

Comment: If you show us sample input data which would generate the undesired duplicate names that would be helpful.

Comment: Distinct might do it though if there are really two people named John at one company, or two locations named Green Acres, I want both.   Basically I want unique people and unique locations for each company.

Comment: added sample data.

Comment: I just wouldn't do that this way. Just return a DISTINCT ordered array, and use json_encode - so none of this GROUP_CONCAT nonsense

Comment: I am using json_encode but on the comma delimited list created by group_concat.  How would you return a distinct ordered array?

Comment: I am not sure distinct works cause I want to have null values where there is null and also include cases where there are really two johns.  Just don't want to have a john for every location and a location for every john (i.e. cartesian product)

Comment: DISTINCT within the GROUP_CONCAT would limit it to giving you unique names per company, but 2 different companies could still contain the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Technically `DISTINCT` should work:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5f8074/1

```
SELECT c.*,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p.name) as `names`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT l.name) as `locations`
FROM companies `c` 
LEFT JOIN people `p`
ON p.companyid = c.id
LEFT JOIN locations `l` 
ON l.companyid = c.id
GROUP by c.id;
```

But according to your comment you want to group even when there are some duplicates.

In this case you can set subquery:

```
SELECT c.*,
  (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(p.name) FROM people p WHERE c.id=p.companyid) as `names`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT l.name) as `locations`
FROM companies `c` 
LEFT JOIN locations `l` 
ON l.companyid = c.id
GROUP by c.id;
```